# The example code of task modifier of SwiftUI is confusing

Tags: swiftui, swift-concurrency

Here is the code in Apple developer document。

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")!
@State private var message = "Loading..."

var body: some View {
    Text(message)
        .task {
            do {
                var receivedLines = [String]()
                for try await line in url.lines {
                    receivedLines.append(line)
                    message = "Received \(receivedLines.count) lines"
                }
            } catch {
                message = "Failed to load"
            }
        }
}
```

Why don't it update `message` in the UI thread as code below

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    message = "Received \(receivedLines.count) lines"
}
```

Does the code in task block alway run in the UI thread?

Here is my test code. It sometimes seems that task isn't inherit the actor context of its caller.

```
func wait() async {
    await Task.sleep(1000000000)
}

Thread.current.name = "Main thread"
print("Thread in top-level is \(Thread.current.name)")

Task {
    print("Thread in task before wait is \(Thread.current.name)")
    if Thread.current.name!.isEmpty {
        Thread.current.name = "Task thread"
        print("Change thread name \(Thread.current.name)")
    }
    await wait()
    print("Thread in task after wait is \(Thread.current.name)")

}

Thread.sleep(until: .now + 2)

// print as follow

// Thread in top-level is Optional("Main thread")
// Thread in task before wait is Optional("")
// Change thread name Optional("Task thread")
// Thread in task after wait is Optional("")
```

Thread in task is different before and after `wait()`

Thread in task is not `Main thread`

Comment: Because task is performed in background queue, but UI needs to be updated in main queue.

Comment: It could be that it is being done on background but. This is the issue we are all facing it seems that is behavior has gotten worse with iOS 15. Submit a bug report using feedback assistant. So many things are “fixed” in SwiftUI with that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question! It looks like a bug, but in fact Apple's sample code is safe. But it is a safe for a sneaky reason.

Open a Terminal window and run this:

```sh
cd /Applications/Xcode.app
find . -path */iPhoneOS.platform/*/SwiftUI.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftinterface
```

The `find` command may take a while to finish, but it will eventually print a path like this:

```
./Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/Modules/SwiftUI.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftinterface
```

Take a look at that `swiftinterface` file with `less` and search for `func task`. You'll find the **true** definition of the `task` modifier. I'll reproduce it here and line-wrap it to make it easier to read:

```
  @inlinable
  public func task(
    priority: _Concurrency.TaskPriority = .userInitiated,
    @_inheritActorContext
    _ action: @escaping @Sendable () async -> Swift.Void
  ) -> some SwiftUI.View {
    modifier(_TaskModifier(priority: priority, action: action))
  }
```

Notice that the `action` argument has the `@_inheritActorContext` attribute. That is a private attribute, but the [`Underscored Attributes Reference`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/ReferenceGuides/UnderscoredAttributes.md#_inheritactorcontext) in the Swift repository explains what it does:

> Marks that a `@Sendable async` closure argument should inherit the actor context (i.e. what actor it should be run on) based on the declaration site of the closure. This is different from the typical behavior, where the closure may be runnable anywhere unless its type specifically declares that it will run on a specific actor.

So the `task` modifier's `action` closure inherits the actor context surrounding the use of the `task` modifier. The sample code uses the `task` modifier inside the `body` property of a `View`. You can also find the true declaration of the `body` property in that `swiftinterface` file:

```
  @SwiftUI.ViewBuilder @_Concurrency.MainActor(unsafe) var body: Self.Body { get }
```

The `body` method has the `MainActor` attribute, which means it belongs to the `MainActor` context. `MainActor` runs on the main thread/queue. So using `task` inside `body` means the `task` closure also runs on the main thread/queue.

Comment: Refer to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856790-init, I know the task inherits the priority and actor context of the caller. But I'm confused about [my test code](https://gist.github.com/MakHoCheung/26e3080407402a464ce6b8f47d6acb29). The result of the code is different running in different environments like playground, cli app and iOS app. Task is always running in a consistent thread in iOS app, but is not always running in a consistent thread in playground and cli app

Comment: I believe top-level code like your test code is not bound to the `MainActor` context, so your `Task` doesn't inherit the `MainActor` context.

Comment: According to [SE-0323](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0323-async-main-semantics.md), if you move your top-level code into an `static func main() async` method on an `@main` type, then it will be bound to the `MainActor` context. Xcode-13.2 should include this behavior.

Comment: That's it. Top-level code is special. Thank you for your help.